# How do i embed a flex grid control in an asp page and pass parameters to the gridcontrol?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, asp-classic

I have done a datagrid in flex and would like to embed it in an asp page. How do i go about that?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use flashVars to send data to the datagrid flex app
2. Create an xml based structure with your data
3. Pass the xml url as flashvars to the flex app.
4. The app should read the xml url from params, load the xml, parse and display it.

How to parse xml and fill dg
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/26/displaying-xml-data-in-a-datagrid/

How to read flashvars 
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/grabbing-flashvars-from-the-embedding-html-template/